# Error building Angular Application

Tags: angular, typescript

While building this application I have kept running into this error "[ts] ',' expected". If I added the comma, saved and tried again the application would run. Now if I stop the local server and try to run it again I have to remove the comma to get the app to run. I would like to know what is going on and what I am doing incorrectly as I have only just started learning how to use Angular.

Error Message

`ERROR in src/app/breeds/breeds.component.ts(35,5): error TS1005: ',' 
   expected.
   src/app/newbreed/newbreed.component.ts(41,10): error TS1128: Declaration 
   or statement expected.
   src/app/newbreed/newbreed.component.ts(45,1): error TS1128: Declaration 
   or statement expected.`

Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breeds',
  templateUrl: './breeds.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breeds.component.css']
})
export class BreedsComponent implements OnInit {
  restItems: any;
  restItemsUrl = 'https://breeds-a648.restdb.io/rest/dogs';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRestItems();
  }

  // Read all REST Items
  getRestItems(){
    this.restItemsServiceGetRestItems()
      .subscribe(
        restItems => {
          this.restItems = restItems;
      },
       (err) => console.log(err), () => {
         setTimeout(() => {
           this.getImages();
           this.deleteBreed();
        },0)
      }
    } <<<<<<< This is where it expects ","

  getImages() {
    let breedName = document.querySelectorAll('#breedName');
    breedName.forEach( (el) => {
      let image = document.createElement('IMG');
      this.http.get(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=&q=${el.innerHTML}&image_type=photo`).subscribe(
        res => {
          image.src = res.hits[0].largeImageURL;
          image.width = '100';
          image.height = '100';
          el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          el.appendChild(image);      
        },
        err => {
          alert("Error occured");
        }
      );
    })
  }

  deleteBreed() {
    let deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.del');
    deleteLinks.forEach( (e) => {
      e.addEventListener('click', (element) => {
        this.http.delete('https://breeds-a648.restdb.io/rest/dogs' + '/' + element.target.id, { headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set("x-apikey", "")
        .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .set('cache-control', 'no-cache') })
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            window.location.href = '/index';
          },
          err => {
            alert("Error occured");
          }
        );
      })
    })
  }

  // Rest Items Service: Read all REST Items
  restItemsServiceGetRestItems() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set("x-apikey", "")
    .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .set('cache-control', 'no-cache');

    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(this.restItemsUrl,{headers})
      .pipe(map(data => data));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing ) in your method:

```
getRestItems(){
    this.restItemsServiceGetRestItems()
      .subscribe(
        restItems => {
          this.restItems = restItems;
      },
       (err) => console.log(err), () => {
         setTimeout(() => {
           this.getImages();
           this.deleteBreed();
        },0)
      }) <-- added closing )
    }
```

Comment: That seemed to work for that section but now I'm getting another error (41,10): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
src/app/newbreed/newbreed.component.ts(45,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: Paste your whole file as one piece of code in your questioin and maybe I can help you..... most IDEs should point out where the error is

Comment: So sorry, rookie move. The error is pointing towards a different file. Time to take a break lol. I will mark this correct because it did fix the error in this file.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.